# Relay command is not getting fired

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have my relay command

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{

   public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    private Action methodToExecute;

     private Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator;

     public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute, Func<bool> canExecuteEvaluator)
    {
        this.methodToExecute = methodToExecute;
        this.canExecuteEvaluator = canExecuteEvaluator;
    }
    public RelayCommand(Action methodToExecute)
        : this(methodToExecute, null)
    {
    }

      public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.canExecuteEvaluator == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            bool result = this.canExecuteEvaluator.Invoke();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.methodToExecute.Invoke();
    }
 }
```

---

My view model

```
public class ViewModel
{

   public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }


    public ViewModel()
    {
        SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(ProcessFile);
    }
    void ProcessFile()
   {
   }
//Some code 
}
```

---

My .xaml

```
 <Button Width="70" Margin="5" Content="Search" Command="{Binding Path= ViewModel.SearchCommand}" ></Button>
```

i have also set data context in starting

`DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

My code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new ViewModel();


        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to set the `DataContext` to `ViewModel` rather than the `MainWindow` itself.

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel class so that the UI knows when SearchCommand has been set.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `DataContext` setting in the XAML and change your constructor to

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = ViewModel;
}
```

Your XAML is binding the data context to the window and not to the view model instance you are creating.

You will also need to change the path to your bindings to be relative to the DataContext (which is now your view model)

```
<Button Width="70" Margin="5" Content="Search" Command="{Binding Path=SearchCommand}" ></Button>

<TextBox Width="300" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=SearchTextBox}"> </TextBox>
```

Comment: Hi steve,i have change constructor.but command is not getting fired.I have added property in my viewmodel public string SerachTextBox { get; set; } and intialize in its constructor to "abc".now i have binded to text box  <TextBox Width="300" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path= ViewModel.SerachTextBox}"> </TextBox> but data is not getting dispayed properly.

Comment: Hi steve,i found soultion i have change my binding.it was typing bug .removed ViewModel.,now its working fine. <TextBox Width="300" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path= SerachTextBox}"> </TextBox>
            <Button Width="70" Margin="5" Content="Search" Command="{Binding Path= SearchCommand}" ></Button>.thanks for solution

Comment: Modified answer to include changes to the bindings that should be made.

Comment: accepting the answer will let people know the issue has been resolved.

Comment: i wanted to vote up but i don't have 15 reputation which require for voting